# I need to turn off ControlState for dynamically generated controls !

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have turned off all the viewstate settings but there is still viewstate in the page, i need to switch the control state off also.

Answer (score 0):

Control state cannot be disabled.

See [Control State vs View State example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx), a few lines down from the top.

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321594/disable-the-control-state).

See [this blog post](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2004/07/01/472.aspx) for a longer discussion about Control State.