# Disable the Control State

Tags: asp.net

How can we disable the Control State of dynamically created controls in Asp.Net 3.5?

Comment: Do you mean the view state? `EnableViewState=false`.

Comment: @silky - No, he means ControlState - http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2004/07/01/472.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can disable viewstate but not control state.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is one of the big advantages of MVC over WebForms - you get to move away from being dependent on bloated ViewState and ControlState blocks on every page.

ControlState is used by lots of WebForms server controls - you can't disable it, but you can avoid it by writing your own ones that render their own HTML.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I generally agree with Rune that you can't do it, but just a random thought:

To use control state, a control explicitly has to call

```
Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
```

on Init. If the controls you add to the page do this, and you reverse it after you've added them to the Controls collection what happens? Can it be reversed?

This sounds a bit stupid, but you might explore.